# NLP: How to look at sentence encoding in torchtext?

Tags: torchtext

```py
TEXT = data.Field(tokenize = 'spacy',
                  tokenizer_language = 'en_core_web_sm',
                  include_lengths = True)

LABEL = data.LabelField(dtype = torch.float)

train_data, test_data = datasets.IMDB.splits(TEXT, LABEL)
train_data, valid_data = train_data.split(random_state = random.seed(SEED))

MAX_VOCAB_SIZE = 25_000

TEXT.build_vocab(train_data, 
                 max_size = MAX_VOCAB_SIZE, 
                 vectors = "glove.6B.100d", 
                 unk_init = torch.Tensor.normal_)
LABEL.build_vocab(train_data)
```

Suppose I have built vocabulary from training data like above. Now I want to take a look of the one-hot encoding of the sentences in the training data, how should I do that? (I know iterator will automatically give the encoded and padded sentence, but I just want to take a look of what the encoding look like).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that these APIs are deprecated now.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can accomplish this is using the `__getitem__` functionality. Check the docs [here](https://pytorch.org/text/stable/_modules/torchtext/vocab/vocab.html#Vocab.__getitem__). You pass in a `string`/`token` as a parameter (e.g. `vocab['cat']`) and it will give you the index of the token in the `vocab`. If you get a sentence from the training data, then iteratively get the tokens for each word, you will get the set of vocab indices for the words in the sentence.